# JavaScript - Image Slider - how to change file source to link source

Tags: javascript, html, image, slider

I've just gone through an exercise based on making an Image Slider.

I've done it step by step, by following a Youtube tutorial.

My images have been placed in my code as files placed in the same folder. Now I would like to change it, so my images would be placed in my code as a links. I mean to make it works without image files directly in my PC but to take it from for ex. Google Pics.

Here's my code so far:

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  
  <style>
   body
   {
    background-color: #222222;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
   }
  </style>
  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
   var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;
   
   var timer1 = 0;
   var timer2 = 0;
   
   function setSlide(slideNumber)
   {
    clearTimeout(timer1);
    clearTimeout(timer2);
    number = slideNumber - 1;
    
    hide();
    setTimeout("changeSlide()", 500);
    
   }
   
   function hide()
   {
    $("#slider").fadeOut(500);
   }
  
   function changeSlide()
   {
    number++; if (number>5) number=1;
    
    var file = "<img src=\"slajdy/slajd" + number + ".png\" />";
    
    document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = file;
    $("#slider").fadeIn(500);
    
    timer1 = setTimeout("changeSlide()", 5000);
    timer2 = setTimeout("hide()", 4500);
   
   }
   
  </script>
  
 </head>
 <body onload="changeSlide()">
 
  <span onclick="setSlide(1)" style="cursor:pointer;">[ 1 ]</span>
  <span onclick="setSlide(2)" style="cursor:pointer;">[ 2 ]</span>
  <span onclick="setSlide(3)" style="cursor:pointer;">[ 3 ]</span>
  <span onclick="setSlide(4)" style="cursor:pointer;">[ 4 ]</span>
  <span onclick="setSlide(5)" style="cursor:pointer;">[ 5 ]</span>
  
  <div id="slider"></div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

I will be greatful, if anyone helps me!

Thanks

Comment: As mentioned, a json array with index and the URL to your image and maybe a function that takes the index value and returns the URL

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

1. Make an array of the links of images you want to display.
2. Loop through each element of the array.

Note that you have to remove the part where you have used the number variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you give me an example. I still don't know exactly how should I do it.. @theruler